# Backup files from Google Drive via Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

This is my script (hacked from someone elses) which works to download files from Google Drive. However when I download a file the created/modified date of my files on my local drive is all the time in which the script was run and that file was processed. In order to be useful I need to be able to preserve the dates of the files as they appear on google drive, such as this:

```
Modified
Jun 10, 2015 by me
Opened
Aug 10, 2016 by me
Created
Oct 23, 2015
```

Is there anyway to change the download script so it keeps the dates of the files intact when they are downloaded to my drive? This is the API reference which I havent been able to find the answer in:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

This is the script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, httplib2, os, datetime, io
from time import gmtime, strftime
from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from datetime import date

#########################################################################
# Fixing OSX el capitan bug ->AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlencode'
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"
#########################################################################

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secrets.json'
TOKEN_FILE="drive_api_token.json"
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive File API - Python'
OUTPUT_DIR=str(date.today())+"_drive_backup"

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, TOKEN_FILE)
    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def prepDest():
    if not os.path.exists(OUTPUT_DIR):
        os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR)
        return True
    return False

def downloadFile(file_name, file_id, mimeType, service):
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    if "application/vnd.google-apps" in mimeType:
        if "document" in mimeType:
            request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
            file_name = file_name + ".docx"
        else: 
            request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/pdf')
            file_name = file_name + ".pdf"
    print("Downloading -- " + file_name)
    response = request.execute()
    with open(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, file_name), "wb") as wer:
        wer.write(response)

def listFiles(service):
    def getPage(pageTok):
        return service.files().list(q="mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
               pageSize=1000, pageToken=pageTok, fields="nextPageToken,files(id,name,mimeType)").execute()
    pT = ''; files=[]
    while pT is not None:
        results = getPage(pT)
        pT = results.get('nextPageToken')
        files = files + results.get('files', [])
    return files

def main():
        credentials = get_credentials()
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
        for item in listFiles(service):
            downloadFile(item.get('name'), item.get('id'), item.get('mimeType'), service)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The best that I could do is to add the createdate here:

```
downloadFile(item.get('name'), item.get('id'), item.get('mimeType'), item.get('createdDate'), service)
```

Comment: I think you can use a combination of the call to get the modifiedTime (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) and then update that time via python's `os.utime` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend you using [gdcp: Google Drive cp](https://github.com/ctberthiaume/gdcp).

All you need to have is:

- Python2.7
- pip

then you need to install those dependencies:

```
$ pip install pydrive
$ pip install backoff
```

And finally, follow the [setup procedure](https://github.com/ctberthiaume/gdcp#setup) in order to link your GDrive account with gdcp and upload/download to/from your GDrive account